# Laravel page expire 419 error on namecheap hosting

Tags: laravel, session, csrf

I am facing a 419 session expire error in Laravel 6.0, csrf token is already present in Login and Register both forms files permissions on cpanel are also 0755

Answer (score 0):

Go to app\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php

update     protected $proxies;    -->    protected $proxies = '*';

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Do not hesitate to use [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to format the code that needs to be changed.